# Trying to rewrite playAudio but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I found this code to play audio files onClick, but it only allows to play one audio file. Now, I'm trying to rewrite the code, but it doesn't work and I can't find the problem. I'm new to JavaScript so if you have a better solution, please let me know.

To understand what I'm trying to accomplish, this is my concept: I'm trying to make a web-based application for mobile (iOS and Android) where childeren can mix sounds to make their own song.  They can drag and drop the sounds into a timeline that will play all the sounds. But before they drag them, they can also play them (so they can hear the sound before dragging them into the timeline, by clicking on a button which contains an image).

This is the original HTML:

```
    <input id="audiofile" type="text" value="" style="display: none;"/>
    <button id="myElement" class="dndplay" onClick="playAudio();" draggable="true"></button>
    <button id="myElement" class="dndplay" onClick="playAudio();" draggable="true"></button>   

    <audio id="myaudio"></audio>
```

This is the original JavaScript:

```
    var currentFile = "";

    function playAudio() {
        var oAudio = document.getElementById('myaudio');

       // See if we already loaded this audio file.
      if ($("#audiofile").val() !== currentFile) {
          oAudio.src = $("#audiofile").val();
          currentFile = $("#audiofile").val();
      }

      var test = $("#myaudio");
      test.src = $("#audiofile").val();
      oAudio.play();   
  }

  $(function() {
      if (Modernizr.audio) {
      if (Modernizr.audio.ogg) {
          $("#audiofile").val("sounds/Stoomloco_Lunetten.ogg"); 
      }
      if (Modernizr.audio.mp3) {
          $("#audiofile").val("sounds/Stoomloco_Lunetten.mp3");
      }
  }
});
```

And this is the code I wrote, but doesn't work:

#### HTML:

```
    <input id="audioOne" type="text" value="" style="display: none;"/>
    <button id="framentOne" class="dndplay" onClick="playAudio1" draggable="true"></button>

    <input id="audioTwo" type="text" value="" style="display: none;"/>
    <button id="fragementTwo" class="dndplay" onClick="playAudio2" draggable="true"></button>   

    <audio id="myaudio1"></audio>
    <audio id="myaudio2"></audio>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
 var currentFile = "";

 var playAudio1 = {

   playAudioOne: function() {
      var fragmentOne = document.getElementById('myaudio1');

      // See if we already loaded this audio file.
      if ((modernizr1, "#audioOne").val() !== currentFile) {
        fragmentOne.src = (modernizr1, "#audioOne").val();
        currentFile = (modernizr1, "#audioOne").val();
    }

    var test = (modernizr1, "#myaudio1");
    test.src = (modernizr1, "#audioOne").val();
    fragmentOne.play();   
},


modernizr1: function() {
    if (Modernizr.audio) {
        if (Modernizr.audio.ogg) {
            ("#audioOne").val("sounds/Stoomloco_Lunetten.ogg"); 
        }
        if (Modernizr.audio.mp3) {
            ("#audioOne").val("sounds/Stoomloco_Lunetten.mp3");
        }
    }
   }
  };

var playAudio2 = {
playAudioTwo: function() {
    var fragmentTwo = document.getElementById('myaudio2');

    // See if we already loaded this audio file.
    if ((modernizr2, "#audioTwo").val() !== currentFile) {
        fragmentTwo.src = (modernizr2, "#audioTwo").val();
        currentFile = (mdernizr2, "#audioTwo").val();
    }

    var test = (modernizr2, "#myaudio2");
    test.src = (modernizr2, "#audioTwo").val();
    fragmentTwo.play();   
},

modernizr2: function() {
    if (Modernizr.audio) {
        if (Modernizr.audio.ogg) {
            ("#audioTwo").val("sounds/Marsmanplein_Ventilator.ogg"); 
        }
        if (Modernizr.audio.mp3) {
            ("#audioTwo").val("sounds/Marsmanplein_Ventilator.mp3");
        }
    }
   }
 };
```

Comment: Nevermind, found something easy to use. Here is the link if you're interested: [link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this might be a bit too much if you're new to JavaScript, but I definitely would recommend you to have a look at the Web Audio API: 
http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html

I've started experimenting with audio in HTML and found the native `<audio>` to be very slow and clunky if you need more, than playing one single song file in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the code from http://www.misfitgeek.com/play-sound-in-html5-and-cross-browser-support-with-backward-compatability/

Basically it is set up to play one sound.  The key line is:

```
oAudio.src = $("#audiofile").val();
```

That means the value of the input section with the id audio file will be the file that plays. You would have to rewrite the code and make it dynamic.  There is a lot of extra stuff you dont need like modernizer if you want to write for android etc.

Maybe start over with http://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/